# Why do different color of the same materal differ temperature in the same sunlight?

Tags: thermodynamics, visible-light, temperature, reflection, absorption

I have a blue, red, and green cup and put a thermometer in each. Of the 3 the blue cup had the coldest temperature inside, then green, then red. I understand there may be differences in the composition of the cups but does color reflect the sun differently? I thought blue being closer to black would be hotter, but it is not?

Comment: This question is more about absorption.  The other question is asking about emission / scattering and how that may or may not relate to absorption.

Comment: @BrandonEnright: Note that the duplicate closure here was *by the asker themselves* and no one else (the "Community" closure occurs when an asker agrees with a duplicate vote). I'm actually pretty confused what's going on here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The blue photon is not being absorbed from the white sun. Compared to red and green photon the blue photon has more energy. That is why most tarps are colored blue to reflect that spectrum and reduce heat. Also there are more blue photons emitted by the sun than the other colors.

Comment: If I wanted a tarp that absorbed the least amount of heat from sunlight, I would look for a _white_ one, not a blue one.

Comment: @jameslarge thanks for the up vote but.  The white one wouldn't block sunlight as well. The base of most tarps are made ofa transparent plastic and the blue dye makes it less transparent and cost is a factor.  You would want a reflective metallic tarp not a white one.